# How to expand and collapse rows using header section in a UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode4.5

I have a table view. Now I want to collapse and expand rows by tapping on the section header. In other words, when I tap the header the rows display for that section. How can I do this?

Comment: do you have structure of data which you need show in tableview? If yes then share it.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.wannabegeek.com/?p=338

Comment: in table view i display only header and when user tapped header...cell display of particular header.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I draft up some code to give you the idea. The concept is we keep track of collapsed section in `NSMutableSet` and add/remove it according to the user touch on the section. The collapse/expand animation is actually the animation of adding/removing cells.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () < UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {
    NSMutableSet* _collapsedSections;
}

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView* tableView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _collapsedSections = [NSMutableSet new];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 3;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [_collapsedSections containsObject:@(section)] ? 0 : 10;
}

-(NSArray*) indexPathsForSection:(int)section withNumberOfRows:(int)numberOfRows {
    NSMutableArray* indexPaths = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
        NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:section];
        [indexPaths addObject:indexPath];
    }
    return indexPaths;
}

-(void)sectionButtonTouchUpInside:(UIButton*)sender {
    sender.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    int section = sender.tag;
    bool shouldCollapse = ![_collapsedSections containsObject:@(section)];
    if (shouldCollapse) {
        int numOfRows = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
        NSArray* indexPaths = [self indexPathsForSection:section withNumberOfRows:numOfRows];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        [_collapsedSections addObject:@(section)];
    }
    else {
        int numOfRows = 10;
        NSArray* indexPaths = [self indexPathsForSection:section withNumberOfRows:numOfRows];
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        [_collapsedSections removeObject:@(section)];
    }
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
    //[_tableView reloadData];
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIButton* result = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [result addTarget:self action:@selector(sectionButtonTouchUpInside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    result.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [result setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section %d", section] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    result.tag = section;
    return result;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell* result =  [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    result.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %d", indexPath.row];
    return result;
}

@end
```

Comment: I copied it from my compilable code and I have tested it. So tell me again why does not it work?

Comment: but i want to collapse table and here table is expanded so tell me now what can i do and thanx for help me...thank you very much

Comment: it worked like a champ. More over i have to put search functionality as well, any idea?

Comment: @MuhammadSaadAnsari Search functionality should be done at data source level. For example, if you are displaying cell by getting data from NSArray, you just have to rebuild your array base on your search filter and call table view's `reloadData`.

Answer (score 3):

As already this is a old question now.Me too also searched and in the last got 1 sample code from Github.So I thought of sharing the link,if in near future any one comes up with the same issues.
https://github.com/iSofTom/STCollapseTableView

Answer (score 1):

[TLIndexPathTools](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools) does this with only a few lines of code on your part. Try running the [Collapse](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools/blob/master/Examples/Collapse/Collapse/CollapseTableViewController.m) sample project. It subclasses `TLCollapsibleTableViewController`, which has a couple of nice options. It supports expanding a single section at a time or multiple sections. It also optimizes the scroll position when you expand a section to show as many rows of the section as possible. So if you tap on a section near the bottom of the screen, it will scroll up automatically.

The full view controller code of the sample project is as follows:

```
#import "TLCollapsibleTableViewController.h"

@interface CollapseTableViewController : TLCollapsibleTableViewController
- (IBAction)toggleSingleSectionExpanded:(UISwitch *)sender;
@end

#import "CollapseTableViewController.h"
#import "TLIndexPathSectionInfo.h"
#import "TLCollapsibleDataModel.h"

#define SECTION1_NAME @"Section 1"
#define SECTION2_NAME @"Section 2"

@interface CollapseTableViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) TLIndexPathDataModel *backingDataModel;
@end

@implementation CollapseTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //define items for two sections
    NSArray *section1Items = @[
                               @"Fredricksburg",
                               @"George Washington",
                               @"Grand Canyon"];
    NSArray *section2Items = @[
                               @"Jelly Bean",
                               @"Bibliography",
                               @"Keyboard Shortcut",
                               @"Metadata",
                               @"Fundamental",
                               @"Cellar Door"];

    //We're using plain string items, so we don't have a sectionNameKeyPath property
    //to use, so instead we explicitly create section info objects
    TLIndexPathSectionInfo *section1 = [[TLIndexPathSectionInfo alloc] initWithItems:section1Items andName:SECTION1_NAME];
    TLIndexPathSectionInfo *section2 = [[TLIndexPathSectionInfo alloc] initWithItems:section2Items andName:SECTION2_NAME];

    //create the backing model, which contains all sections and items
    self.backingDataModel = [[TLIndexPathDataModel alloc] initWithSectionInfos:@[section1, section2]
                                                                           andIdentifierKeyPath:nil andCellIdentifierKeyPath:nil];

    [self collapseAll];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *item = [self.dataModel itemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = item;
}

- (IBAction)toggleSingleSectionExpanded:(UISwitch *)sender {
    self.singleExpandedSection = sender.isOn;
    [self collapseAll];
}

- (void)collapseAll
{
    self.dataModel = [[TLCollapsibleDataModel alloc] initWithBackingDataModel:self.backingDataModel
                                                        collapsedSectionNames:[NSSet setWithArray:self.backingDataModel.sectionNames]];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

configure viewForHeaderInSection:

like this

```
(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{


    UILabel *lblHeader = [[UILabel alloc]init];

        lblHeader.text = @"Section 0";        

    lblHeader.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    lblHeader.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size:18];
    lblHeader.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    lblHeader.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    UIGestureRecognizer *gr;
if(section==0){
    lblHeader.text = @"Section 0";  
    gr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
}else if(section == 1){
    lblHeader.text = @"Section 1";  
    gr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture1:)];
}



    [lblHeader addGestureRecognizer:gr];
    return lblHeader;
}
```

then write seperate action calls

```
- (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer { 
}

- (void)handleGesture1:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer { 
}
```