# Expand/collapse rows using header section in a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

Hello I have implemented example [Expand Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248021/how-to-expand-and-collapse-rows-using-header-section-in-a-uitableview)

```html
-(void)sectionButtonTouchUpInside:(UIButton*)sender
{
//    sender.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    int section = sender.tag;
    
    bool shouldCollapse = ![collapsedSections containsObject:@(section)];
    if (shouldCollapse)
    {
        int numOfRows = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
        NSArray* indexPaths = [self indexPathsForSection:section withNumberOfRows:numOfRows];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        [collapsedSections addObject:@(section)];
    }
    else
    {
        int numOfRows = 0 ;
        switch (section)
        {
            case 0:
                numOfRows = (int)aArray.count;
                break;
            case 1:
                numOfRows = (int)bArray.count;
                break;
            case 2:
                numOfRows = (int)cArray.count;
                break;
            case 3:
                numOfRows = (int)dArray.count;
                break;
        }
        
        NSArray* indexPaths = [self indexPathsForSection:section withNumberOfRows:numOfRows];
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        [collapsedSections removeObject:@(section)];
    }
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

My program crashed in above code with this message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of rows in section 2.  The number of rows contained in an
>   existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of
>   rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus
>   the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted,
>   1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of
>   that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

**Update**

```html
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(![_collapsedSections containsObject:@(section)])
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        int count = 0;
        switch (section)
        {
            case 0:
                count = (int)aArray.count;
                break;
            case 1:
                count = (int)bArray.count;
                break;
            case 2:
                count = (int)cArray.count;
                break;
            case 3:
                count = (int)dArray.count;
                break;
        }
        
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont have any idea how this program will deleterows from given arrays and how it will again populate to show them.

Comment: Move [collapsedSections addObject:@(section)]; & [collapsedSections removeObject:@(section)]; before inserting or deleting rows from Table.

Comment: The error your facing is due to the fact that your model is not updated. Model here is your array. Whenever you want to delete a row, you need to delete that particular object from the array first and then call the tableView delete function. Since any tableau updates will recall numberOfSections, numberOfRows and cellForRowAtIndexPath methods.

Comment: Use this code http://cl.ly/aje1/download/ExpandTable.zip

Comment: Updated according to your approach http://cl.ly/ajsi

Comment: Many Thanks Respected Brother Abid. I am overviewing your code and trying to understand it. :) I am new to ios :), and will inform you if found any difficulty. May i have your skype id or any other contact detail.

Comment: dear abid. Thank you very much your latest code worked amazingly.Though i could not understand the logic but it is wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

if(section == 0)
{
  return [__collapse containsObject:@(section)] ? 0 : [self.section1 count];
}
else if(section == 1)
{
   return [__collapse containsObject:@(section)] ? 0 : [self.section2 count];

}
else if(section == 2)
{
     return [__collapse containsObject:@(section)] ? 0 : [self.section3 count];
}
else
{
    return 0;
}
```

}

Modify this method like above..

Comment: Ok Mr.Jr Developer :) thanks for your reply. I have already implemented the  protocol method as mentioned in above update, but found above error.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

{

```
    int count = 0;
    switch (section)
    {
        case 0:
            count = (int)aArray.count;
            break;
        case 1:
            count = (int)bArray.count;
            break;
        case 2:
            count = (int)cArray.count;
            break;
        case 3:
            count = (int)dArray.count;
            break;
    }

    return count;
```

}

Try this..

For Ur Code..Initially ur rows are 0. So, After u click event methods try to insert ur array no.of.rows.. Thats causing error.

Comment: thanks for your reply . . . problem is solved by Mr.Abid Hussain.