# Expanding And Collapsing Sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, rows, sections

Can somebody suggest me how to implement the following in Objective C?

When I click on a section rows for that particular section alone expand. How do I know which section is clicked and how do I return rows count for that particular section?

Note: I have kept a button in my section. And when i click rows of all the sections get expanded and again when i click on a section rows of all the sections get collapsed.

Comment: Refer this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248021/how-to-expand-and-collapse-rows-using-header-section-in-a-uitableview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expanding and collapsing tableView sections iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27729150/expanding-and-collapsing-tableview-sections-ios)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note :-** My TableView Cell height is 126, but when i run my application, TableCell height is 75 (As i mention below), when i pressed on TableCell than automatically TableCell height expand.

**See :-** int myCurrentSelection=9999; // Set globally.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

int myrow = (int)indexPath.row;

if (myCurrentSelection == myrow) {
    myCurrentSelection = 9999;
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
} else {
    myCurrentSelection = myrow;
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:245/255.0 green:245/255.0 blue:245/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
[self.tblView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
}


-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGSize boundingBox = [mutArrMessages [indexPath.row][@"message"] boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake((self.tblView.frame.size.width - 86),MAXFLOAT)
                                                                              options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                                           attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont helveticaNeueLightFontOfSize:17.0]}
                                                                              context:nil].size;
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(ceil(boundingBox.width), ceil(boundingBox.height));
if ([indexPath row] == myCurrentSelection) {
    return (MAX((size.height + 46),76)) + 50;
}
return (MAX((size.height + 46),76));
}


-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{    
 return 76;
}
```