# Click on fixed specific cells will expand or hide certain cells below

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UItableview that I wish to click on specific cells（like a sections header）then will expand or hide some cells below it. I checked there are lots of guide talked about expand just one cell, but not multiple. Can someone guide me on how to do that ? Thanks all.

Comment: This is a common feature, and there are plenty of guides (even entire libraries) on this exact thing. Even just googling "UITableView collapse header" returns several viable results. There are even some here on SO, like this answer here (it's Obj-C, but shouldn't be too hard to read): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248021/how-to-expand-and-collapse-rows-using-header-section-in-a-uitableview

Comment: Have 1 cell as the header cell. Create a variable `isExpanded`, then set it true / false as a toggle based on user's selection of the cell. In your `UITableViewDataSource` depending on `isExpanded` set the number of rows in sections as actual value + 1 or 1 (to represent the header cell).